# How to force Metro style app to update its UI/screen from another non-Metro app?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-8

I am doing custom drawing around the mouse pointer on desktop and/or on top of all windows. I am calling InvalidateRect() and UpdateWindow() to refresh the windows after the mouse moves. This works except on Metro apps and Start Screen. The Metro apps' screens are not refreshed via above method. How can this be achieved?

I know Metro apps are run in the same desktop, and their window handles can be found.

But, when I split the Windows 8 desktop (for Explorer's desktop and Metro app's screen), above refresh method works.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure, but I'd look into the DWM (Desktop Window Manager) functionality for possibly better ways to do the onscreen drawing.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please show any example? But I am currently using GDI+ to draw. The problem is how to refresh full-screen metro style apps' screens while drawing on them.

Comment: Oh. It's a lot of work to delve into that, for no guaranteed result. And since I'm not the one needing this functionality, I must respectfully decline the offer to help out with that. :) Well, anyway, GDI+ is not a problem in itself, but as I recall it has some off-by-one pixel placement bugs and some extreme inefficiency for text. Inefficiency in drawing for mouse cursor associated things might translate to undesirable flicker.

Comment: SOLVED using SetWindowPos(). Thanks.